# Set Back title by the default for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

This is how

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    VAXApplicationSettings.configureApplicationAppearance()

    window =  UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    if let window = window {
      guard let welcomeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WelcomeViewController") as? VAXWelcomeViewController else {
                return nil

      }


      let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: welcomeViewController)

      window.rootViewController = navigationController
    }



    return true
}
```

On the Welcome View Controller I push New View Controller which looks like this:

[image]

And as you see here is a Cancel button.

This is a source code of class of pushed view controller:

```
import UIKit

class NewViewController: UIViewController
{
  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(back))
  }

  func back()
  {
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the pushed view controller set the `leftBarButtonItem` of its `navigationItem`? That will replace the back button.

Comment: @rmaddy, I've edited my question with more details.

Comment: But how do we know what `VAXApplicationSettings.configureApplicationAppearance()` does? Obviously it could do something here that would affect this! For example maybe it uses the appearance proxy.

Comment: Also this line is just plain wrong: `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(back))`. You should never set the target/selector for a back button. "Back" functionality is built-in! Just let the system do what it does.

Comment: @matt, I answered my question. thanks for your comments. I am not sure how I did that )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your navigation controller or your navigation bar. The back button's title is, by default, the title of the view controller you would *go back to* if you tapped it. *That* view controller can also change the title of the back button that goes back *to it*. There is no overall "default"; it happens on a view controller by view controller basis.

Comment: this is really weird. as I can find where I changed it, so no fragments of code where I set some custom button or any other.

Comment: There must be. You would never see "Cancel" appear all by itself. Something, somewhere, is called "Cancel". Do a global search on the word "Cancel" to find it!

Comment: Maybe the button was set in Interface Builder and it's a system type so you won't find the text "Cancel" in code in that case.

Comment: @rmaddy But that would not be a back button, would it?

Comment: @matt If it's set as the `leftBarButtonItem` then it would replace the back button.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i've set this for navigation item in my Welcome View controller which is root view controller of navigation controller.

Comment: That is actually what I said in my answer. The view controller you _go back to_ gets to say what the back button that _goes back to it_ should say.

Comment: This is all well and good but not particularly reusable, it's only real downfall.

Answer (score -1):

For situations like this I like to create a sublass of `UIViewController` called `BaseViewController` Then all my view controllers inheirit from this instead of the standard iOS one. This allows me to add functionality that is applied throughout the app.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Default, target: self, action: #selector(back))
    }

    func back() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Ideally your app should be built from the start using this but you can do an app-wide find/replace to update your existing view controllers.

Comment: it does not help, still has cancel button

Comment: Do not do this. There is no need to do this.

Comment: It might well be `leftButtonItem` not `backButtonItem` as rmaddy suggests. I often get them round the wrong way.

Comment: Swap `backButtonItem` out for `leftButtonItem` as rmaddy says and try that.

Comment: I answered my question.